# Flight company cancelled flight and didn't provide alternative - should they refund my new (more expensive) ticket?

Tags: germany, air-travel

Through Opodo, I bought a flight ticket from Münster to Oslo on 8 July, via München. It was a Lufthansa flight. On 4 July Opodo e-mailed me that Lufthansa cancelled the flight. I should wait up to 48 hours, and they would give me an alternative flight. I did not hear anything from them. After 48 hours, I called Opodo on 6 July and they said there were no alternatives. I actually found some alternatives myself, but they said it was not applicable because it wasn't Lufthansa. Since I still had to go to Oslo, I bought a new ticket myself. I bought the cheapest ticket I could find but it was a lot more expensive then before (about 450 euros). It was with Norwegian Air.

Should Opodo refund my new ticket?

As far as I know, flight companies are obliged to provide alternative flights if they cancel one.

I already tried to contact them twice about this issue through their customer service, giving them two weeks to respond. Unfortunately they did not respond at all. I am ready to involve a lawyer but I would like to know if there is any chance to succeed.

Comment: I believe the obligation to replace the flight only exists if the cancellation is within a certain period of time before the scheduled departure.  If no one else answers in the next day or so, I'll look it up and post an answer -- no time right now.

Comment: But there was an alternative, it was the one you used...  Once you determined that the Norwegian Air flight met your schedule needs did you relay this information to Lufthansa and give them an opportunity to respond?  Many airlines have code sharing agreements and they might have been able to help.  Unfortunately once you go outside  their system you lose leverage.  At this point probably the best you could hope for is a credit towards some future booking.

Comment: when I called them, I had already found some alternative routes, but they told me it had to be Lufthansa.

Comment: > [Law Stack Exchange is for educational purposes only and is not a substitute for individualized advice from a qualified legal practitioner](http://law.stackexchange.com/help/disclaimer). Communications on Law Stack Exchange are not privileged communications and do not create an attorney-client relationship.

Comment: The European Consumer Centres Network provides free legal advice and support on cross-border purchasing issues. It can also help consumers deal with disputes relating to travelling in the EU, Norway, and Iceland. If you have tried to resolve a dispute with a business to no avail, [click here](https://www.eccnet.eu/contact-your-local-ecc) to contact your local ECC and submit an enquiry.